# MVC4 JQuery validate fails to validate non-required fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I get MVC4/JQuery Validate to apply validation to nullable properties?

For instance I have 2 numeric properties in the model:

```
    [Required]
    public int Counter { get; set; }

    public int? CounterNonRequired { get; set; }
```

And this Razor code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Counter)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Counter)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CounterNonRequired)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CounterNonRequired)
</div>
```

This produces the following HTML:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line" 
           data-val="true" 
           data-val-number="The field Counter must be a number." 
           data-val-required="The Counter field is required." 
           id="Counter" 
           name="Counter" 
           type="number" 
           value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" 
          data-valmsg-for="Counter" 
          data-valmsg-replace="true">
    </span>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line valid" 
           data-val="true" 
           data-val-number="The field CounterNonRequired must be a number."
           id="CounterNonRequired" 
           name="CounterNonRequired" 
           type="number" 
           value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" 
          data-valmsg-for="CounterNonRequired" 
          data-valmsg-replace="true">
    </span>
</div>
```

The CounterNonRequired editor should validate that only numbers may be entered, but instead it is allowing letters etc. The Counter editor prevents letters being entered.

I also tried to use a regex to validate the non-required field, but this was ignored in the same way as number validation.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

**View**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Page", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmIndex" }))
 { 
    <div>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Counter)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Counter)
    </div>
    <div>
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CounterNonRequired)
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CounterNonRequired)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CounterNonRequired)
    </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Save" style="float: left;" id="btnSave" title="btn" name="ButtonType" />
}
```

**Model**

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Counter { get; set; }

    public int? CounterNonRequired { get; set; }
}
```

**Script** use in View

```
<script src="~/Script/Jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it's not allow letter in `CounterNonRequired` text box and if you enter letter in text box it fire the message like `The field CounterNonRequired must be a number.`

Comment: I was using jquery 1.8.2 which was included in the MVC template. I dropped back to 1.8.1 as in your example and it still doesn't work. What version of jquery.validate are you using?

Comment: @ChaoticNadirs Version 1.8.0